# bootstrap button look different in official website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

To a lot of people it might seem a very stupid question but recently i was working with twitter bootstrap.

When i start using it , i reliazed that it looks different in official twitter bootstrap website and in my webpage when i using the same files and the same CSS as provided in the bootstrap examples.

But after comparing the images , i see the look and feel is different. I am not sure what i am missing. Is anybody already came across this situation. i am using version 3.2.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you switch browsers?

Comment: No same browser firefox...

Comment: The button with the bevel is either version 2 of bootstrap or the bootstrap theme.css that comes with the latest version. The row of buttons is the default 3.x style

Comment: I have bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.theme.min.css. So i should remove the theme file.?

Comment: Essentially look at your css and if there is a bootstrap-theme.css or theme.css then that's why your buttons and other elements look different, remove it and the look with match

Comment: Yeah, that's the non-flat optional theme. Full demo: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/